# React - Issue with button onClick for void array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

- I can't get void values from buttonAction array void for button onClick.
- I can get the length value in the array correctly. but I can't get the array value at all.
- Can anyone help me see the error? Thanks.

Navbar.tsx

```
<div className="items">
<Popup 
show={true} 
title={"Popup"} 
buttonText={["Button1","Button2"]} 
buttonAction={() => [redirect(), redirect2()]} >
</Popup>
</div>
```

Popup.tsx

```
import React from "react";

//styled
import {Area} from "./index.styled"

import Button from "../button";

type Props = {
    show: boolean;
    title?: string;
    desc?:string;
    buttonText:string[];
    buttonAction:() => void[];
}

const Popup: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    if (!props.show) return null;
    return (
        <Area>
            <div className="content">
                {props.title && <h3 className="title">{props.title}</h3>}
                {props.desc && <p className="desc">{props.desc}</p>}
                <>
                    {props.buttonAction().map((value:void, index, array) => {
                        return(
                            <Button primary key={index} onClick={() => {value}}>
                                {index}
                            </Button>
                        )
                    })}
                </>

            </div>
        </Area>
    )
}

export default Popup;
```

Comment: If its void, what you are expecting in the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`() => void` is just the typing for a function with no parameters that returns nothing. You presumably want to map these to your button clicks.

I recommend adjusting your code as follows:

Create a type for your popup buttons, eg. `PopupButton`.
Each button has a `text` and an `action`.

```
type PopupButton {
    text: string;
    action: () => void;
}
```

Now change your props to accept `PopupButton`s

```
type Props = {
    show: boolean;
    title?: string;
    desc?:string;
    buttons: PopupButton[];
}
```

And finally map the `props.buttons` data to your `Button` components and bind their action/text.

```
<>
    {props.buttons.map((button, index) => {
        return(
            <Button primary key={index} onClick={button.action}>
                {button.text}
            </Button>
        )
    })}
</>
```

Understand that:

- A new type was created to define the data needed for each button (text and action)
- The type of `action` is `() => void`, ie. a parameterless function with no return type
- `action` was bound to the `onClick`

Comment: Thank you  I know the void function not return value, my mistake forgot the function. It's fixed now, thank you again.